# Javascript validation and updating HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have currently ran in to 2 issues and need some assistance.

Firstly I am creating a simple form that checks simply for empty values on submit and alert() if there are any empty. Currently when i fill in the form values and click submit, I am alerting the value on the name text which is always empty and it doesn't work properly?

The second issue is updating HTML with a message depending on what time it is, I feel as if i am almost there with both of these

If someone could tell me how my code looks from a visual perspective that would be great too!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Get current time and hours
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var currentHour = currentTime.getHours();

  var getHeading = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

  //Form fields
  const contactName = document.getElementById("contact-name").value;
  const contactEmail = document.getElementById("contact-email").value;
  const contactPhone = document.getElementById("contact-phone").value;
  const contactMessage = document.getElementById("contact-message").value;
  const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitbtn");

  //Declare emailMessage as empty string, ready to be changed.
  let emailMessage = '';

  //Ternary statement for current time, returning the emailMessage.
  currentHour < 9 || currentHour > 22 ?
    emailMessage = "I am asleep, sorry!" :
    emailMessage = "contact me.";

  getHeading.innnerHTML = emailMessage;

  //Form validation, post.
  submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(contactName);
    alert(contactName);

    contactName && contactEmail && contactPhone && contactMessage !== '' ?
      alert("Please complete form") :
      console.log("no");
  })

});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<section id="contact" class="contact-me container">
  <div class="container-content">



    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="test"></p>
      <form>
        <p>
          <label for="contact-name">Your Name</label>
          <input id="contact-name" type="text" name="contact-name" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="contact-email">Your email address</label>
          <input id="contact-email" type="email" name="contact-email" /> </p>
        <p>
          <label for="contact-phone">Your phone number</label>
          <input id="contact-phone" type="tel" name="contact-phone" /> </p>
        <p>
          <label for="contact-message">Your message</label>
          <textarea id="contact-message" name="contact-message" rows="5"> </textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input id="submitbtn" type="submit" value="send my message" onsubmit="submitForm()" /> </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your original code, the `contactName`(and others) sets when page is loaded and will never be changed since you save it as a const. So you have to get the value after you click the submit button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Get current time and hours
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var currentHour = currentTime.getHours();

  var getHeading = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitbtn");
  //Declare emailMessage as empty string, ready to be changed.
  let emailMessage = '';

  //Ternary statement for current time, returning the emailMessage.
  currentHour < 9 || currentHour > 22 ?
    emailMessage = "I am asleep, sorry!" :
    emailMessage = "contact me.";

  getHeading[0].innerHTML = emailMessage; // a typo here

  //Form validation, post.
  submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Form fields
    const contactName = document.getElementById("contact-name").value;
    const contactEmail = document.getElementById("contact-email").value;
    const contactPhone = document.getElementById("contact-phone").value;
    const contactMessage = document.getElementById("contact-message").value;


    console.log(contactName);
    alert(contactName);

    contactName !== '' && contactEmail !== '' && contactPhone !== '' && contactMessage !== '' ?
      console.log("no") :
      alert("Please complete form");
  })

});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<section id="contact" class="contact-me container">
  <div class="container-content">



    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="test"></p>
      <form>
        <p>
          <label for="contact-name">Your Name</label>
          <input id="contact-name" type="text" name="contact-name" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="contact-email">Your email address</label>
          <input id="contact-email" type="email" name="contact-email" /> </p>
        <p>
          <label for="contact-phone">Your phone number</label>
          <input id="contact-phone" type="tel" name="contact-phone" /> </p>
        <p>
          <label for="contact-message">Your message</label>
          <textarea id="contact-message" name="contact-message" rows="5"> </textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input id="submitbtn" type="submit" value="send my message" onsubmit="submitForm()" /> </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and changes buddy, unfortunately after entering all of the values and submitting, it still alerts saying Please complete form? Do you know how to get around this? Thank you again!

Comment: Fixed, I forgot to change this part of codes before. You have to compare if each variable is empty individually and note that ternary operator : `condition ? val1 : val2`, if `condition` is true then `val1`